# Building Ghostscript from source on Linux/UNIX

Tags: installation, ghostscript

I am executing below step to install Ghostscript software on Unix environment.

- tar -x ghostpcl-9.23-linux-x86_64.tgz
- cd ghostpcl-9.23-linux-x86_64

After this when I'm executing ./Configure I'm getting below error:
No such file or directory.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have autotools installed. Then, in the directory where you installed the source code, do:

```
./autogen.sh
make
```

Provided you have all ther required tools and components, that should build it for you. If you want debug versions then type 'make debug'. If you want to rebuild then 'make clean' and 'make'.

Any time you get new source start with ./autogen.sh

Comment: I get no acceptable C compiler found in the path when I run ./configure command.

Comment: Well firstly, what I said was "./autogen.sh", not "./configure". Secondly, if you don;t have a working C compiler, how do you expect to compile a C program ? You need to have gcc installed, you may well require other tools as well.

Comment: thanks ken for your valuable comments. I'll update you once I get C compiler installed in my machine